# Alternative to iStat Menus on Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

Since iStat Menus doesn't work yet with Snow Leopard, is there another tool that I can use that would give me comparable info? (fan speed, computer temp, memory used & cpu usage)

Comment: iStat Menus has now been updated to work with Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer would probably be a combination of smcFan Control (http://www.eidac.de/ ), and MenuMeters....

Between both of those, I believe you will have the feature set you have asked about, and plus more...

Comment: Thanks, I like how smcFan lets you set higher fan speeds too. That and MenuMeters will definitely do until the iStat Menus update

Answer (score 4):

There's a public beta of [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) available that supports Snow Leopard. It's got most of the functionality of iStat Menus (and a few things that iSM doesn't have). I don't think it has fan speed readouts, though.

Comment: Or just wait for iStat Menus :)

Comment: @alex: I'm actually using both in 10.5 right now -- iSM doesn't have the live-updating menubar activity indicators for disk/network Tx/Rx.

Answer (score 4):

iStat Menus 2.0 is out : http://www.islayer.com/apps/istatmenus/